# Problems creating a .csv download

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download

I am trying to create a .csv download from a mysql table without much success. I have put together the code below from a tutorial that I found here http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/ but for some reason the .csv file that is downloaded contains the entire source code of the page not the column headings and data from the mysql table.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=site-list-export.csv');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('id', 'url', 'clean_host', 'keyword', 'group', 'page_number', 'page_authority', 'domain_authority', 'page_mozrank', 'seomoz', 'page_title', 'check_inbound', 'check_inbound_priority ', 'count', 'project', 'type'));


    // fetch the data
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connect);

    $rows = mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM `url_list_google`
    WHERE `group` = '".$selected_group."' 
    GROUP BY clean_host 
    ORDER BY `domain_authority` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($connect);

    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);

    }
```

Comment: You could always install phpMyAdmin, as it supports database exportation in CSV format.

Comment: So in short the problem is that **the PHP code is not executed by the web server**. Do other PHP files work? If yes, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained this a bit better. Yes all other PHP files are being executed and the code above is only a small snippet out of a php page that is functioning except for the download .csv part. There is a button that will allow site users to download a .csv file of their data. This is that part that isn't functioning correctly. If you look at the following page you will hopefully see what I am trying to achieve http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/ Thanks :-)

Comment: add `exit;` after your loop over the rows.

Comment: Eugene you are a legend!!! Adding exit; pulled all of the data through but I still had all of the source code from above my script included. So I just moved my script to be the very first thing on the page. Awesome! Thank you :-)

Comment: @EugeneManuilov it might be worth moving your comment into the Answers section

Comment: @meetalexjohnson just added :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `exit;` function call after your loop and it will prevent else content rendering.